# filter pandas based upon True condition without using mask

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a pandas DataFrame without using mask by using `.filter()` but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my example:

```
df1
   numbers    Name
0  0          Tom
1  3          Harry
2  2          John
3  1          Mary
```

I want to filter all rows where numbers <2 so like this:

```
df1
   numbers    Name
0  0          Tom
3  1          Mary
```

I have tried to do this using `.filter` with this solution:

```
df1.filter(df1.numbers < 2)
```

I get True/False for the parameter but filter filters everything out.

Can someone explain or provide a different solution please. Thanks

Comment: You are close, need `df1[df1.numbers < 2]`

Comment: This is a boolean mask

Comment: I would like to attain this result using a method @jezrael

Comment: If check [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), it working with columns names only, so not possible filtering by boolean mask

Comment: @jezrael is there any method that can achieve this?

Comment: I found really hacky awfull solution - `df1.T.filter(df1.index[df1.numbers < 2]).T`

Comment: What is problem use `df1[df1.numbers < 2]` ?

Comment: @jezrael I cannot method chain with this

Comment: I got it, need [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/2901002), `df.query('numbers < 2')`